# What is the philosophy behind making instance variables public by default in Scala?

Tags: scala

What is the philosophy behind making the instance variables public by default in Scala. Shouldn't making them private by default made developers make less mistakes and encourage composition?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, you should know that when you write:

```
class Person( val name: String, val age: Int ) {
   ...
}
```

`name` and `age` aren't instance variables but accessors methods (getters), which are public by default.

If you write instead:

```
class Person( name: String, age: Int ) {
   ...
}
```

`name` and `age` are only instance variables, which are private as you can expect.

The philosophy of Scala is to prefer immutable instance variables, then having public accessors methods is no more a problem.

Comment: In your second example, `name` and `age` could also just be constructor parameters and not instance variables, depending on how they are used in the body of `Person`.

Answer (score 5):

Private encourages monoliths.  As soon as it's easier to put unrelated functionality into a class just because it needs to read some variables that happen to be private, classes start to grow.

It's just a bad default and one of the big reasons for classes with more than 1000 lines in Java.

Scala defaults to immutable, which removes a massive class of errors that people often use private to restrict (but not remove, as the class' own methods can still mutate the variables) in Java.

Answer (score 3):

1. with immutables which are preferred in many places, public isn't so much of an problem
2. you can replace a public val with getters and setters without changing the client code, therefore you don't need the extra layer of getters and setters just in case you need it. (Actually you do get that layer but you don't notice it most of the time.)
3. the java anti pattern of private field + public setters and getters doesn't encapsulate much anyway

Answer (score 3):

(An additional view supplementing the other answers:)

One major driver behind Java's encapsulation of fields was the uniform access policy, i.e. you didn't have to know or care whether something was implemented simply as a field, or calculated by a method on the fly.  The big upside of this being that the maintainer of the class in question could switch between the two as required, without needing other classes to be modified.

In Java, this required that everything was accessed via a method, in order to provide the syntactic flexibility to calculate a value if needed.

In Scala, methods and fields can be accessed via equivalent syntax - so if you have a simple property now, there's no loss in encapsulation to expose it directly, since you can choose to expose it as a no-arg method later without your callers needing to know anything about the change.